# How can Lutris be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, lutris

I need Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'm hoping to install Lutris on it. When I attempt to install it using a PPA package, the package `lutris` is not found. The procedure for attempting this is as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

When I attempt to download a TAR of Lutris and then to run its Python executable `bin/lutris` I encounter the error `ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi'`, in spite of the fact that the Python module `gi` is already installed.

So how might Lutris be installed on 16.04?

Comment: "Python module gi is already installed." installed how? The PPA only has packages for 18.04+

Answer (score 2):

You can use [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/retrogames), it provides Lutris 0.4.18 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samoilov-lex/retrogames
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

If this version does not suit your needs you can install Lutris 0.5.6 from Lutris PPA:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-distro/python3-distro_1.0.1-2_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python3-distro_1.0.1-2_all.deb

wget https://launchpad.net/~lutris-team/+archive/ubuntu/lutris/+files/lutris_0.5.6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./lutris_0.5.6_amd64.deb
```